# Mobile Push Device ID Android SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-android

Is the DeivceID that is visible in Marketing Cloud (on Contact) after registering a device via MobilePush SDK is unique to the device or is it a system generated value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Deviceid is unique to the device and assigned upon install of the app. if the app is deleted and reinstalled a new deviceid is assigned